# How to organize multiple microservices in a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, microservices, github, repository, continuous-delivery

I am setting up a Github repository for a project that will have multiple Microservices.

I have created a sub-directory for each microservice under One Repository.

```
ProjectRepository
    \Services
         \MicroService1
         \MicroService2
         \MicroService3
    \OtherThings
```

Every MicroService will be developed by a separate team member, and tagged and deployed independently.

Do you foresee any problem with this? (as against one Repository per Microservice).

Comment: Your exact same question was closed as opinion based on StackOverflow. Why would it be different here?

Comment: But if you want *my opinion*, I'd say that setting up a good microservice architecture is very hard and most projects that went down that road would have been far better off with a (modular) monolithic approach. Mainly because most projects don't even have the problems that microservices can solve, so there's no reason to suffer the additional pain microservices cause. I forsee many problems if you continue on this path and how to organise your Git repository will turn out to be the least important one.

Comment: Rik D, thankyou for your inputs. This question is not about opinion, it's about what technical problems will one face with this kind of repository. I get that Microservices are not for every situation, and that's so true. AWS Lamda functions can be thought of as Microservices, in which case we face the same questions about repository layout.

Answer (score 3):

> Every MicroService will be developed by a separate team member, and tagged and deployed independently.

Therefore they "should" be in separate repositories.

(I note that one team member per repository is a *terrible* development anti-pattern; does that mean work stops when they go on holiday? The minimum team size should be two.)

It's not an overwhelming problem either way; giant companies manage to do real work both with thousands of fragmented repositories or [one, colossal, whole-company repo.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/)

The main downside of having more than you need in one repo is that each copy takes up more space; this isn't SVN where you can just check out a subtree.